# Placing multiple overlays as a user

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps, overlays

I've been working on a project to create a map (using googles api) where the user can longpress to place custom overlays. So far I've been able to allow the user to place one overlay, but when you go to place the second the program crashes. I suspect it's because the method attempts to reuse the same variable name? Here's the segment of code I'm using, any help as to how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onLongPressFinished(MotionEvent e, ManagedOverlay overlay, GeoPoint point, ManagedOverlayItem item) {                   
    if (item != null)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected..." + item.getTitle() + "!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ManagedOverlay managedOverlay = overlayManager.createOverlay("listenerOverlay", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tankicon));

        managedOverlay.createItem(point, "text");

        overlays.add(managedOverlay);
        overlayManager.populate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag with language

Answer (score 0):

please try this one. This is used for showing multiple overlays on map view, may be it will solve the problem: https://github.com/donnfelker/android-mapviewballoons

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I simply used the onDoubleTap method instead of the longPress. The longPress turned out to be way to problematic as it could be misinterpreted, and sometimes did not work.

The bulk of the code is still the same however.

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e, ManagedOverlay overlay, GeoPoint point, ManagedOverlayItem item) {
    ManagedOverlay managedOverlay = overlayManager.createOverlay("Location", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));

    managedOverlay.createItem(point, "place");
    overlays.add(managedOverlay);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You selected " + managedOverlay.getName() + " !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    overlayManager.populate();
```